# Does separating your Javascripts into separate files have performance implications?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm writing a PhoneGap(Cordova) app with jQuery and jQuery Mobile.

I'm a noob, so for simplicity I like to keep my scripts in separate .js files, with functions divided between them roughly according to function.

(1) Are there performance implications to this method?

(2) Are there programmatic effects that this has that I'm unaware of?

(3) Since it's a Cordova app, all the files will be pre-packaged, but does this turn into a better/worse idea when you're talking about a classically-accessed website?

Thanks!

---

### EDIT

Since asking this question, I found this blog post. http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/. It addresses the issue of multiple HTTP requests and the associated performance issues, albeit in the context of images.

Comment: as far as i know the answer is "no noticable performance implication"

Comment: If you were talking about a web application, with separate scripts fetched in separate HTTP transactions, then there are performance considerations. For you, however, since they're packaged up and directly available, it won't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes:

   - It takes longer to load several small files than one large file.
   - The scripts are executed in order, so with several files you have a load - run - load - run cycle, where each file can't be loaded until the previos has run.
2. The scripts run in order, so if one depends on another, they have to be in the right order.
3. If it's loaded as one package, the network transfer time would be the same, but the process of loading the scripts into the page is still somewhat more complicated with several scripts.

Comment: Do you have any kind of estimate on how much difference it could make or maybe a resource that attempts to explain? It seems like this would be a marginal performance gain in a situation where latency doesn't matter. @JasperMogg What I do for production is place my separate JS files into a single one after minifying them, along with a short description of what each bit of code does. That way I still develop with the separate files but when I'm ready to push an update live I minify and concoct. Anyone else have another approach that they like?

Comment: @Jasper: A tool like Yslow can help you pinpoint potential performance problems.

Comment: @Guffa thanks, but my app won't run in a browser because of the way it's structured. I'll bear that in mind for future projects though!

Answer (score 1):

1. Normally it does not effect performance much, but reduces the no. of requests generating from client browser.
2. There are no programmatic effects of keeping js in seperate files.
3. For a classic website, its good to keep it the way you are using.

as far as I understand, it is a design issue, and you need to keep balance between factoring/cumulating your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It will have no noticeable impact when executed by the client machine. However, having lots of separate JS files can have a noticeable impact on perceived load time by the user. This is one aspect of something called "page weight".

Each file requires a separate request to look up and then download the file. For small or low traffic sites, this will not matter much. But as usage goes up, it can become very noticeable.